# how to properly create a foreign key?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, ddl

I have the below SQL

```
mysql-sql> create table Employees (Emp_ID int not null primary key, Emp_Name varchar(20),Hours_LoggedIn int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)
mysql-sql> insert into Employees (Emp_ID,Emp_Name,Hours_LoggedIn) values (001,'Dinesh',9);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)
mysql-sql> insert into Employees (Emp_ID,Emp_Name,Hours_LoggedIn) values (002,'Shruthi',8);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
mysql-sql> insert into Employees (Emp_ID,Emp_Name,Hours_LoggedIn) values (003,'Sukanya',7);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
mysql-sql> insert into Employees (Emp_ID,Emp_Name,Hours_LoggedIn) values (004,'Varun',6);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
mysql-sql> insert into Employees (Emp_ID,Emp_Name,Hours_LoggedIn) values (005,'Karthi',5);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)


mysql-sql>  create table Project (Project_ID int not null primary key,Project_Name varchar(20),Project_Manager varchar(20),CostPerHour int,Minimum_LoggedInHours int,foreign key(Minimum_LoggedInHours) references Employees(Hours_LoggedIn));
```

Am getting the below error.

```
ERROR: 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

I need to use Hours_LoggedIn as FK. Can anyone help with the correct code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL requires any column referenced by a foreign key to be indexed. Try the following:

```
ALTER TABLE Employees ADD INDEX hours_logged_in_idx(Hours_LoggedIn);
```

before creating the project table. Note that since Hours_LoggedIn is not necessarily unique that this may cause unexpected behavior.